# How to connect to an online excel from my local excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel data file stored on box.com. Say the url of the file to be https://box.com/file/302595154 .
I need to connect to this file from my local excel file and read data.
I only need to read data and update not required.
I need to supply credentials to box.com before I can acccess the data.

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

use this link.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Forms-Blog/Forms-for-Excel-new-experience-for-Excel-survey-in-Office-365/ba-p/109195

step by step follow. 
Thanks You

Comment: Thanks Vishal. I will try and let you know

Comment: Vishal, the forms for excel help only with OneDrive. My files are stored on box.com and I cannot create forms for excel. This solution may not work for my need.